# Fail with AdHoc distribution for iPhone 2G

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks, distribution, adhoc

I have some issues with my application. So, first time I have deployed the application for AdHoc distribution everything went well on my device and on my tester device (iPhone 2G).

Now when he starts the new build on his device he is seeing the splash screen and after this the app crashes. The only thing changed on this new version is that I have added some new feature to the app, but nothing on the first screen. My iOS version is 4.3, xCode 4 and iOS SDK 4.3 and my tester has an iPhone 2G and iOS 3.1.3. The target for the app is set to 3.1.2.

I have included the following frameworks:
1) libz.1.2.3.dylib;
2) libxml2.dylib;
3) MobileCoreServices.framework;
4) CFNetwork.framework;
5) UIKit.framework;
6) CoreGraphics.framework;
7) QuartCore.framework;
8) SystemConfiguration.framework.

Could one of them be the cause? How can I find out what frameworks are available for, let's say, iOS 3.1.3? Currently all frameworks are set to "required".

Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this issue? I will post the code for the first screen if you find it relevant.

Thank you,
Andrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to inspect the logs on your tester's device to find the cause of the crash.  The console log may provide some help -- your tester can retrieve the console log by using the iPhone Configuration Utility that Apple provides.  It can be downloaded from http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/ for both OSX and Windows.  If your tester downloads and runs this, it will give him a view pretty similar to the Organizer window in Xcode.  Have him click his device on the left-hand side, and then the "Console" tab, and then save the log and send it to you.

The other thing that might (more likely) help is the crash log.  If your tester connects to iTunes and does a sync, the crash log is copied to his computer.  It can be found in

`~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>` for MacOS

and either
`C:\Documents and Settings\<USERNAME>\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/<DEVICE_NAME>` or `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>` for Windows.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I have sent the details to my tester and I am waiting for the crash reports. Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If your app is crashing on startup, you'll need to gather his crash logs and read those. There's a million ways an app could crash; we'd need a lot more information to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you. But how can my tester gather this information? He does not have xCode, just the phone. And on my devices (iPhone 4 & iPhone 3 GS & iPhone 3) the app is running fine.